# NTP Problems - sntp: too many bad or lost packets

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse, ntp

I need some help from you guys regarding NTP on Suse.

I have a server, whose IP is 192.168.100.52, which is based on Suse Linux and here is my NTP conf file:

```
server 192.168.100.11  iburst
restrict 192.168.100.11
logfile /var/log/ntp
```

192.168.100.11 is another NTP server in the network.

Now, when other linux systems have their ntp server as 192.168.100.52, the NTP service starts, but time does not sync.
In the NTP clients, on `ntpdate <IP>` or `sntp <IP>`, the error I get is: "sntp: too many bad or lost packets".

On the NTP server (192.168.100.52), I get this error in the log file (`/var/log/ntp`):

```
15 Jan 16:38:21 ntpd[15262]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
```

Also when I do `ntpdate <IP>` or `sntp <IP>` on the NTP Server, I get: "sntp: too many bad or lost packets".

The server is plain installation of OpenSuse along with MySQL installed.
SuseFirewall is disabled and there is no other antivirus or firewall in place.
All ports are open, still not able to sync from server (also the NTP server is not able to sync with any other machine).

How can I get it working?

Comment: what's does `ntpdate -d 192.168.100.52` say? Have you tested w/o the restriction first?

Comment: @djf This is the output of 192.168.100.52

sntp: too many bad or lost packets

when i try sntp 192.168.100.52 I get the same above error

Comment: Remove the line `restrict 192.168.100.11`.  Also, remove the "iburst" suffix from the "server" line then stop/start `ntpd`. See if that helps.

Comment: @BruceEdiger that didnt help too ... still getting "ntpd exiting on signal 15" in logs and sntp: too many bad or lost packets on ntpdate

Comment: That is the entire ntp.conf? What was wrong with the default config file from Suse? I am not sure why someone said remove iburst, iburst is good. But that restrict line was awful